# Stop onBindViewHolder() while scrolling recyclerview

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a RecyclerView adapter and in each view holder I have nested view group (TagGroup https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup)
The performance is horrible while scrolling with these nested ViewGroups
My adapter even uses sethasstableids(true) which speed up scrolling performance slightly 
My question: Is there any way to stop certain parts of onBingViewHolder() code while scrolling i.e. the section where the view group is populated 
I know so that some image loading libraries have way to stop loading image while scrolling

below you can see the TagGroup (ViewGroup) in each view holder

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-fCQa73GiDYZDgtMXJoR2k2M045Nm10dDRRLXA4RW9YaGZB/view?usp=sharing